# How to get data from an <ul> to a php file (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to return the data-id from an `ul` on click, the data-id needs to go to a .php file and I want to use javascript(jquery ofc) I'm really new with java-script so I have no experience please someone help.
Here is my `ul`:

```html
<ul id="zones">
    <?php foreach ($data as $id => $name): ?>
        <li data-id="<?= $this->e($id) ?>"> <?= $this->e($name) ?> </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

the name of my html file is dashboard_zones.html and the php file I want to acess the data-id is dashboard.php

Comment: Where is the `select`?

Comment: I don't have a select just a ul, do I need a select?

Comment: Your title says you have a `<select>` element...

Comment: I was gonna do it with a select, but then I changed my mind because this looked better

Comment: Oh sorry, that was from the last question I tried to do

Comment: And what is your actual _question_ now? Don’t know how to get the attribute value inside the click handler? Go research it! Don’t know how the sending the value to the server part will work? AJAX, go read up on it. Did that, but still “not working”? Then show us what you tried; but please go read [ask] first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a generi [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  call, with a `$.each()` loop like:

```
var ids = [];
$('#zones li').each(function(){
    let current_id = $(this).data('id');
    // you can eventually test for undefined id
    if(typeof current_id === "undefined"){
        return; //acts like "continue;"
    }
    ids.push(current_id);
});
$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {your_ids: ids},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (theResponse ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I didn't tested it, but I assume you can start from this code to do what you need